# Function seq.fold_left

Tags: dictionary, sequence, z3, solver

I am unable to successfully utilize the seq.fold_left function.

```
(declare-const s (Seq Int))
(declare-const t (Seq Int))
(declare-fun f (Int Int) Int)

(define-fun sum_seq ((s (Seq Int)))
  (seq.fold_left (lambda (acc x) (+ acc x)) 0 s)
)

(assert (= t (seq.fold_left f s 0)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Can you identify the problem as I have encountered some errors?

```
(error "line 6 column 3: unknown sort 'seq.fold_left'")
(error "line 9 column 33: unknown constant seq.fold_left ((Array Int Int Int) Int (Seq Int)) ")
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues here.

- The function is actually called `seq.foldl`, though I see your confusion since the documentation advertises it as `seq.fold_left`. Probably a matter of the code not matching the documentation, hopefully they'll fix it. You might want to file a ticket at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues to alert the developers to the discrepancy.
- Your lambda-expression isn't right. In SMTLib, you have to annotate each variable with its type. So it should be something like `(lambda ((acc Int) (x Int)) (+ acc x))`
- In your `assert`, you're using the arguments in the incorrect order. Should be `0 s`, not `s 0`. Also, the result is an `Int`, not a `Seq Int`, so equating that to `t` is type-incorrect.

So, here's an example that actually works:

```
(declare-const s (Seq Int))
(declare-const t Int)

(define-fun sum_seq ((s (Seq Int))) Int
  (seq.foldl (lambda ((acc Int) (x Int)) (+ acc x)) 0 s)
)

(assert (= t (sum_seq s)))
(assert (> (seq.len s) 3))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

This prints:

```
sat
(
  (define-fun s () (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 5) (seq.unit 6) (seq.unit 7) (seq.unit 8)))
  (define-fun t () Int
    26)
)
```

which is a correct model for the given constraints. Hope this helps you sort out your own code.

Comment: Many thanks! Your response resolved my inquiry. I had been facing difficulties for a while and did not consider that the problem was with the name. I will make note of this issue to inform other developers.

Comment: They just pushed in a fix https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/02d48adae556ca0e472ec19dfc1dab414e2e55b1, so if you compile from sources you can use the name `seq.fold_left`. (Along with `seq.foldl`.)